# Autodeploy with git

Tags: git, github, web-deployment

I have investigated options to deploy my web project to production server after git push.
As far as I understand there is 2 options:

1. Create git repository on production server and use git post-receive hook to perform some deploy tasks.
2. Add webhook url to git repository on github. On production server create script which will be handling requests to url specified on github.

In my case second option is more preferable because I already use github for my project. But I am not sure how can I set access to this url, so only github will triger script under webhook url.
Or maybe there is other options to auto deploy github project.

Comment: not related to github so I don't put that in a direct answer, gitolite documentations provide nice ideas (and can be used separately from gitolite) : http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/deploy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search got github webhook listeners [like this one](https://github.com/zenhacks/github-webhook-listener):

> Listener for receving signals sent by github.com through web hook. It mainly:

- listening for POST request from github at port 3000
- parse the JSON and fetch the information about the

  - repository name
  - repository url
  - the commit after push
- pass the above information through environment variable REPO_COMMIT
- spawn an process for deployment

> only github will trigger script under webhook url

Even if another http request were made to this url (not from github), its content should still be a valid JSON message with the right information (like [in this example](https://gist.github.com/gjtorikian/5171861)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy to servers you can use a service like deployhq.com, or if you prefer to do it yourself take look at [deployogi](https://github.com/coderofsalvation/deployogi) (its based on bash and deployogi-hooks, and was designed specifically for this)